# Get Checked Options In Model On HttpGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkboxfor

I m working on online examination i want to preserve answers of students on http get i just want the checked checkbox on http get,i have them in my query i just want to add them in my model

My Model

```
 public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionOption> Options { get; set; }
    public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionOption> SelectedOptioncheckBox { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionOption 
{
    public int OptionId { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
 Question Q = new Question();

                Q.SelectedOptioncheckBox = new List<QuestionOption>();
                List<int> ChkOptions = studBal.GetCheckedAnswers((int)TestId, model[count].QuestionId, (int)(studBal.getStudentId(Session["sname"].ToString())));



                for (int i = 0; i < ChkOptions.Count(); i++)
                {
                    Q.SelectedOptioncheckBox.Add(ChkOptions.ElementAt(i))
                }
```

My Query

```
var data = (from temp in context.Student_Answer_Master
                            where temp.Test_Id == TestId && temp.Question_Id == QuestionId && temp.StudentId == StudentId
                            orderby temp.Option_Id ascending
                            select (int)temp.Option_Id).ToList();

return data;
```

My View

```
<div>     
                                @if(chk==null || chk.Count()==0)
                                {
                                      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].Options[j].IsChecked, new { id = "selectedOption" + (j + 1) })
                                      @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Options[j].OptionId)
                                }
                                 else if (chk [0]== Model[i].Options[j].OptionId)
                                {
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].SelectedOptioncheckBox[j].IsChecked, new { id = "selectedOption" + (j + 1) })
                                      @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Options[j].OptionId)
                                }


                                 <span>@Model[i].Options[j].OptionName</span>

                            </div>
```

As you can see the query it gives me checked options in list **ChkOptions** from database i just want to add that **ChkOptions** in my model field that is  **SelectedOptioncheckBox** so that i can show the check boxes that are already check on my view

Comment: just post your view...

Comment: i hv posted my view plz check it...

Comment: in beginform give FormMethod.Get instead Post...@user3831519

Comment: plz stuy the information Form method is not an issue and i m submiiting the answers on post method and then retrieving it on get so